# Inverse to starts_with() in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have `df` that has variables with the following names:

```
> names(df)
 [1] "local authority: district / unitary (as of April 2015)" "oslaua"                                                
 [3] "December 2014"                                          "X__1"                                                  
 [5] "March 2015"                                             "X__2"                                                  
 [7] "June 2015"                                              "X__3"
```

I know I can select those variables that start with `X__` by using a function `df %>% select(starts_with("X_"))`.

My question is whether there would be a function that makes it possible to select exactly those variables that do not start with `X__`. The output should give something similar to `df %>% select(! starts_with("X_"))`. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. You can use `-` to negate the selection/drop variables:

```
df <- data.frame(X_1 = 1:3, X_2 = 2:4, Y_1 = 1:3, Y_2 = 2:4)

df %>% select(-starts_with('X_'))

#  Y_1 Y_2
#1   1   2
#2   2   3
#3   3   4
```